# Password manager (autofill) integration in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a simple way to integrate password autofill (like lastpass) in a flutter TextField?

Comment: Check here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633695/flutter-password-autofill

Answer (score 3):

Flutter now supports autofill (password, email, username, etc.). There is an existing [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13015) about text fields trigger to support autofill and is now closed. Check [this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13015#issuecomment-592099210), for the [merged PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/52126) with example.

> This PR (as well as the engine PRs) adds the most basic autofill
> functionality. It does not include some platform-specific
> configurations (e.g., passwordRules on iOS).
>
> ```
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return AutofillGroup(
>       child: Column(
>         children: <Widget>[
>           TextField(controller: username, autofillHints: [AutofillHints.username]),
>           Checkbox(
>             value: isNewUser,
>             onChanged: (bool newValue) {
>               setState(() { isNewUser = newValue; });
>             },
>           ),
>           if (isNewUser) TextField(controller: newPassword, autofillHints: [AutofillHints.newPassword]),
>           if (isNewUser) TextField(ontroller: repeatNewPassword, autofillHints: [AutofillHints.newPassword]),
>           if (!isNewUser) TextField(controller: password, autofillHints: [AutofillHints.password]),
>         ],
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> ```

But if you are specifically looking for LastPass support, this is a Flutter limitation atm. There is a [ticket filed in GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27918) regarding this issue.